# Is there a sendKey for Mac in Python?

Tags: python, macos, sendkeys

In Mac 10.6, I want to cause an active application to become de-active, or minimized by Python

I know I could use sendKey in Windows with Python, then what about in Mac?

Comment: sendkeys is a windows api to send a keypress to an application window progmatically.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is what I found from a different question on Stack Overflow. It works pretty good for my problem.

```
import os
cmd = """
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "m" using {command down}' 
"""
# minimize active window
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: I was looking for how to do this in Ruby and the same idea can be used as well...  

    `puts \`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "m" using {command down}'\``

or pass in a file to do additional osascripting  

    `puts \`osascript example.as\``

Answer (score 8):

Try [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/), an Apple event bridge available in PyPI:

```
from appscript import app, k
app('System Events').keystroke('N', using=k.command_down)
```

Comment: Please note that appscript is no longer developed or supported, and its use is not recommended for new projects.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Yinan, which will send the keystroke to the currently active application, you can send it to a specific application as follows. Pass the following to osascript as before, or save it to a file and pass the file to osascript

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using {command down}
end tell
```

This will send *Cmd + r* to Safari after bringing it to the foreground

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could run an OSA script (man osascript) from Python, for instance, and drive the application?

Answer (score 0):

To make my scripts which already work on Windows using `SendKeys` from `pip` also work on OS X, I made a file `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SendKeys/__init__.py` (`site-packages` is where `pip` puts everything it installs on my Mac... not sure if that's configurable or not.)

The contents of the file are:

```
def SendKeys(keys):
    if keys == '{ENTER}'
        keys = 'return'
    from os import system
    system('osascript -e \'tell application "System Events" to keystroke ' + keys + "'")
```

Obviously it's not very robust, so I won't be putting it on `pypi`, but it's enough to make my scripts run on both OS X and Windows.