# Automate 'enter' key in Python (on a Mac)

Tags: python, macos, automation, automated-tests

I'm creating test automation for an application.  I am using a testing tool to do most of the testing, but in order to get to that point I first need to automate one 'enter' key click in Python.  I am using a mac, so pywin32 is not available.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[Appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) makes this pretty easy:

```
from appscript import app
app('System Events').keystroke('\r')
```

This will send the keystroke to whichever application is in front.

Comment: Doesn't OSX also use `\n` nowadays?

Comment: Behavior might vary, but I just tested \n with this comment submission, and only \r worked.

Answer (score 0):

By looking around, I found the [answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770312/is-there-a-sendkey-for-mac-in-python) in another question similar to yours.

You're going to have to change up the code a little bit so that it's 'Enter' not Ctrl-r, but it should be easy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/
- https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

```py
    import time
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller   
    keyboard = Controller()
    # Press and release space
    keyboard.press(Key.space)
    keyboard.release(Key.space)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import atomacos

def send_multiple_keys(app,keychr):

    """Send multiple key character(Keyboard Key) with no modifiers."""
     """ app here is the bundle id of the application being used"""

    application=atomacos.getAppRefByBundleId(app)
    application.activate()
    application.sendKeys(keychr)
```

atomacos can be used for automation on mac OS
https://pypi.org/project/atomacos/