# hide pygame window on OSX

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, pygame

Pressing command-H in OSX immediately hides the active window. How do I achieve the same effect, programmatically, from Python? Specifically, I'd like to find a particular window that my application creates and then be able to show & hide it programmatically.

I already know how to do this with `pywin32` but I'm afraid my expertise there doesn't quite cover OSX as well.

If it helps, the window in question is one created by pygame. I know that pygame has `pygame.display.iconify()` but that doesn't satisfy my requirements - the window doesn't disappear immediately, but rather the disappearance is animated, and there's no corresponding "uniconify" function that I can find.

Comment: Will this Q&A help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770312/is-there-a-sendkey-for-mac-in-python

Comment: @Paul: nice, maybe! i'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: @Paul: hmm unfortunately pygame doesn't seem to respond to CMD-H ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this ended up working. When I want to hide the window, I do `pygame.display.quit()` and make my code properly handle not having a display. When I want to show it, I do `pygame.display.set_mode(...)` with the former resolution.

The net effect is that of hiding & showing the window. Unfortunately the window gets created in a different spot than where it started, and although apparently you can tell SDL to create the window in a particular spot, I haven't been able to find a way to get the window's location...