# Passing variable from python to applescript

Tags: python, applescript, osascript, keystrokes

I'm trying to make a python script pass characters from a text file as keystrokes into OSX.
The text file is formatted as a column of characters:

Which is being read into a list (called lines). This bit seems to work, as when I type lines[3], for example, the third character is printed, as expected.

I'm now trying to use applescript to pass this character as a keystroke to OSX, using the following:

```
import os 
for f in xrange ( VALUE ):
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke linesf]'
```

It doesn't seem happy about the list[f] part (syntax error, carat is beneath the final apostrophe). I suspect it's because the variable f is not available to this command, for some reason, but I'm not certain. Could anybody give any advice? I know that the bit in the for loop needs to be indented, but this dialogue won't let me indent it, for some reason. It is correct in the script that I am testing.

Thank in advance.

Edit:

Those were typos, it should be lines, not list, the colon should be there, and it should be indented. After fixing all of this, I have the same result. I can't just iterate through the list, this is only an excerpt of the for loop, it needs to be structured this way for the rest to work.

How do I fix the line beginning osascript?

I got this by editing the accepted answer from this question, by the way:
[Is there a sendKey for Mac in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770312/is-there-a-sendkey-for-mac-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

What it's unhappy about is that you've tried to use a command line instruction within your Python program - Python sees `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke list[f]'` and thinks that you want to subtract `e` from `osascript`, but then has no idea what to do with the string `'tell application "System Events" to keystroke list[f]'`.

There are many things you're doing wrong here. First off, the code you've posted can't possibly be what you actually have, because you're missing the colon from your `for` loop (it should be complaining about that instead) and haven't indented the code that goes inside your `for` loop. Second, you've imported `os`, which I assume you want in order to use `os.system` for your command line instruction. Third, you should not call a list `list`, because the name `list` is already in use for the actual list class (this is a useful thing to have around, because, for example, it lets you do things like `list('foobar')` to create the list `['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']`). Fourth, if you want to loop over each item in a list, [actually do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383250/why-should-i-use-foreach-instead-of-for-int-i-0-ilength-i-in-loops/4383321#4383321). Fifth, if you write a string like `"keystroke x[y]"`, then the variables `x` and `y` (assuming they exist) are irrelevant: you've asked for the string to contain the actual letters `'x'` and `'y'` (and some square brackets). You need to actually build a string that contains the appropriate character from the list.