# Open text file and search on OS X

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I would like to open a text file and then search immediately for a certain string and highlight it.

I use:

```
command ="open "+'"'+ file +'"'
os.system(command)
```

But I want something like:

```
command ="open "+'"'+ file +'"' + "then"+ "ctrl-F(string)"
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there a way to do this? I just want the text in string to be highlighted as it is with a normal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: The `open` causes the associated application to start running and load the file, so the `ctrl-F` + string would have to be sent to that app in a way that looked like a keypresses. [_Is there a sendKey for Mac in Python?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770312/is-there-a-sendkey-for-mac-in-python) may help.

Comment: Whether this is possible depends on whether the app in which the file will be opened takes a command-line argument indicating that strings matching the given string should be highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with `open`; to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (I'm assuming you're on OS X from your tags), you can use AppleScript to tell the System Events application to perform a keystroke:

```
os.system("open " + filename)

# You may need to add a sleep() here if the application is not already open and therefore needs time to load
os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {command down}'""")
os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke \"""" + search_term + "\"'")
```

Comment: I would use triple-quoted strings at the Python level so as to avoid having to escape those double quotes.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Yes – I was considering that whilst trying to figure out which backslashes go where, but I wanted it to be concise and avoid the unnecessary variables created in the question.

Comment: What unnecessary variables? I'm just recommending using triple quotes instead of double quotes for those two string literals—for example, `"""osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {command down}'"""`.

Comment: How would I do logical and within `search term`? For example, can it match  "cat" and "dog" even if they don't appear side by side?

Comment: @user99889 No - this simply triggers the system "Find" option and so is limited by what you would be able to do with CMD+F within the application as per usual.