# Is there a Python equivalent to Java's AWT Robot class for MAC

Tags: java, python, macos, selenium

I am working on a webpage automation (using selenium webdriver in python) where I need to upload a file.

I am working on mac and tried the following approaches:

```
 - I tried using send_keys but the same didn't work (threw following error: cannot focus element
 - AutoIt doesn't work since it is MAC.
```

I came across java.awt.robot to get this kind of thing work but is there anything similar which is available for python.

An example will help me a lot.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment. Please refer to this below post:

[Is there a sendKey for Mac in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770312/is-there-a-sendkey-for-mac-in-python)